# How would I go about creating a blender lite version (if possible)

Tags: add-on

So I understand this is a pretty strange question. Basically, I want to create a very lite version of Blender. All I want is to import STL files to view them and maybe rotate and move them around. I don't want any of the other features of blender. Is something like this even possible to create with the source code or am I dreaming here. If this is possible, how would I even go about starting this? Thanks for baring with me.

Comment: Is your goal to create something similar to a kiosk mode or do you want a binary that only contains the bare minimum required code? The former could potentially be accomplished through an add-on hiding UI elements and disabling shortcuts, the latter would require extensive modifications to the source code, which wouldn't be worth the effort just to create an stl viewer.